# How to sort an HTML table within a Flask app?

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I currently have a Flask app that reads data from an SQL server and displays them through an HTML table. I would like to be able to sort the table by clicking on a respective column. If that is not possible then how about sorting the data in advance using the Time column and then just displaying the sorted table?

This is the app:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Orders(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'
    OrderID = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    TableNo = db.Column(db.Integer())
    Item = db.Column(db.String())
    Quantity = db.Column(db.String())
    Number = db.Column(db.String())
    Time = db.Column(db.String())

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Order: ' + self.OrderID

@app.route("/Orders")
def html():
    orders = Orders.query.all()
    return render_template('Page.html', orders = orders)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
    html()
```

This is the html code which reads the data from SQL database.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<link href="static/style.css?versop" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"</link>

<h1> AI Waiter <h1>
    <h2> Orders </h2>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>OrderID</th>
            <th>TableNo</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Served</th>
        </tr>

    {% for orders in orders %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{orders.OrderID}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{orders.TableNo}}
        </td>
        <td>{{orders.Item}}</td>
        <td>{{orders.Quantity}}</td>
        <td>
            {{orders.Number}}
        </td>
        <td>{{orders.Time}}</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox"><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    </table>
```

Comment: If you want the HTML to do something, you will also have to share the HTML... Also, probably the best solution is not to do in with flask/on the back end, but do it with JS on the front end, if you want to do it responsively.

Comment: Why are you not sorting the Queries using SQL itself?

Comment: @DebdutGoswami "I would like to be able to sort the table by clicking on a respective column." OP, you should look into [JS](http://jsfiddle.net/g9eL6768/2/) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach will be the following steps:

1. Send the primary keys of the query result as a list to the Jinja template beside your main query, i.e. "orders".
2. Pass the list to the JS function where your sorting is controlled.
3. Send the list back to Flask on a separate route with async request.
4. On Flask route function, use SQLAlchemy to rebuild the query based on the primary key list.
5. Sort the query.
6. Jsonify the query and send it back to JS.
7. On JS, replace the original table HTML with the new sorted data.

The potential problem is that if your table is very large, say larger than 1000 rows, the rebuilding of query may trigger the "too many SQL variables" error, which I don't have a good solution to currently.